# как отправлять на сервер каждый раз новый id при нажатии на чекбокс react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, graphql

Подскажите новичку, как в React при нажатии на чекбокс отправлять его id на сервер для получение данных.

Есть список с чекбоксами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при нажатии на какой то из чекбксов его id записывается в локальный стейт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, запрос летит на сервер, полученные данные записываються в стейт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только данные записаны в стейт нужно обнулить **brandId** и так по кругу, каждый раз добавляя к **testArr** новые данные, и если чекбокс нажали снова удалить данные с testArr

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
 const handleBrands = (e) => {
     setBrandId(e.target.value);
};


useEffect(() => {
    if (brandById){
        setTestArr(oldArray => [...oldArray, brandById]);
    }
}, [productsAll, brandById]);



   <Checkbox checked={} mode="yellow" name={name}label={name}onChange{handleBrands}/>
```

Работает но только на добавление в массив, при повторном нажатии не удаляються.
И при загрузке страницы testArr выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так было:

```
setBrandId(e.target.value);
```

А так должно быть:

```
setBrandId(e.target.checked);
```

Comment: В таком случае передается true в brandId. 
Это не совсем то что мне нужно,